# Silverlight 4 Unit Testing; Wrong Version of mscorlib is loaded

Tags: c#, unit-testing, silverlight-4.0

I have been trying to develop some unit tests for a Silverlight 4 project in MSTest but I am having some trouble getting them to run.  In my code, I am using some expressions (System.Linq.Expressions) and they are working correctly when I run the program under normal circumstances.  If any of this code is encountered during a unit test however, I get a 'MissingMethodException' on the type 'AppDomain'

I have traced the issue to the fact that 'AppDomain' is defined in mscorlib.dll.  When I run the program normally, version 2.0.5.0 of mscorlib (Silverlight 4) is loaded, and under unit tests version 2.0.0.0 is loaded.  All of the references in both my test and normal project are correct so I can't really figure out why MSTest is loading the wrong version.

**Is there some way to get MSTest or VSTestHost to actually load the proper version of mscorlib? (2.0.5.0)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using one version of the .NET framework to run the tests, and another to run your code under normal circumstances. Silverlight and .NET are compatible enough that Silverlight assemblies can often be used from .NET without problems (even if Visual Studio gives you a warning on the reference), but there are a few exceptions.

For example, running Silverlight code this way, you cannot use any of the Silverlight UI classes. (Any FrameworkElement, DependencyObject, Dispatcher or similar) as these require the correct runtime. I am not surprised that AppDomain also falls into this category.

To work around this problem, you can either make sure to only test code that has no dependencies on classes like the above, or you can cross compile your source code as full .NET projects. The latter does not solve the incompatibilities for you, but allows you to compile slightly different versions of your code to let the code compile and run cleanly.

Note that mscorlib is not a .NET assembly like any other, it's full of nasty native code references and cannot be used in any meaningful way outside of its intended runtime.

Comment: hmmm... those options don't seem reasonable.  Why does this have to be so hard?

Comment: I'm sorry if they don't agree with you, those are the choices that you have. It's so hard because .NET and Silverlight are two different runtimes, they just happen to look quite similar and happen to use the same binary file format for modules (assemblies).

Comment: it's not your fault.  It just seems that there is some way to make this happen.  I can manually load mscorlib(2.0.5.0) into the Test's application domain manually, but haven't quite figured out how to get it to jive.

Answer (score -1):

SL4 is not compatible with MSTest. You must create a SL4 Unit-test project (this is a special project) - then set this to be the startup project. And when running this project, unit-tests are executed with a small UI (in a browser) showing the results of the executed unit-tests.

**Edit:**
Some have success with unit-testing using MSTest. However in order to do this, you must do several tricks. And the unit-tests are not executed in a SL4 environment, so the unit-test results are not valid.

Comment: MSTesting has worked with Silverlight for some time now.  You can install the Silverlight 4 tools for Visual Studio that includes a silverlight test project template.

Comment: Try reading this: forums.silverlight.net/t/138721.aspx/1aa. ...We're working on a command-line solution that can ship in the Silverlight Toolkit, unfortunately the MSTest and Visual Studio integration for unit testing does not work with Silverlight tests today...

Comment: Morten, in theory you are correct, they use different runtimes, and even if you work around the problems, you will not be testing "the same thing". However, may people (including myself) have successfully used conventional unit testing frameworks with Silverlight assemblies, or cross compiled Silverlight code.

Comment: @MortenFrederiksen That forum thread you linked to is over two years old.

Comment: "Are not valid" is a very absolute statement. In the same way I assume that unit tests running in a 32 bit system are not valid (if the system will ever run as a 64 bit process). Is a different version of Windows "valid"? Different processor manufacturer? You need to decide the level of abstraction that you need, for testing business logic the tricks are just fine, for testing say networking or file IO, not so much ...